# SP groups are not displaying in modern communication site OTTB web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, audience-targeting, communication-site

Why SP groups are not showing while typing in the target audience section of modern communication site OOTB web parts?

Is there any other way to map SP groups in OOTB web part target audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint groups are **not supported** for audience targeting in SharePoint online modern experience.

> Azure AD groups (including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported with the exception of AAD dynamic groups.

**Documentation**: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

> Currently you can only use AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups to target audiences.

**Source**: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)

You can vote on below similar SharePoint UserVoice so that Microsoft will implement these features at earliest:

1. [Allow using SharePoint groups to target audiences in quick links web part](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42712238-allow-using-sharepoint-groups-to-target-audiences)
2. [Navigation audience targeting support SharePoint groups](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/40584448-navigation-audience-targeting-support-sharepoint-g)